# Chern-Simons Functional for $S^1$-bundles over Riemann Surfaces

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, gauge-theory

If $M$ is a closed, orientable 3-manifold $M$ and also happens to be an $S^1$ bundle over some Riemann surface $\Sigma$, then it seems like a natural Heegaard splitting of $M$ could come from splitting $\Sigma$.

One may then do some Heegaard Floer theory which studies the intersection of two Lagrangians. Each Lagrangian represents $SU(2)$-flat connections defined on half of $M$ and the intersections of the Lagrangians correspond to flat connections which are defined on all of $M$.

These flat connections are also the critical points of the Chern-Simons functional. I'm hoping that the functional has some additional properties when we know that $M$ is a circle bundle which makes it easier to study its critical set. For example, might it look a little bit like the moment maps that Kirwan studied in her thesis? Those are degenerate but still manageable. Then, on the Lagrangian side of things, one can say something about the intersection.

I imagine that this question about the functional is addressed in the literature but I'm not familiar with gauge theory and searching for key terms has so far been unfruitful for me.

Comment: I don't see how you can get a *handlebody* decomposition on $M$ from a decomposition of $\Sigma$. One would get a decomposition of $M$ into two manifolds with boundaries unions of tori. The Chern-Simmons functional on circle bundles was investigated  throughly in the 90s in two books, one by Taubes,  and one by Kronheimer, Mrowka and Ruberman.

Comment: @Liviu You perhaps mean Morgan-Mrowka-Ruberman, the book on moduli spaces of unperturbed instantons? They get some results on R x circle bundle.

Comment: Yes, those instantons limit flat connections on circle bundles and they had to analyze carefully  the moduli  space of flat connections on circle bundles.